# Unable to create new claim identity

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

I am currently trying to expose a field from an authenticated user, but I'm having a bit of difficulty trying to add a new claim to the authenticated user.

In MVC5 I would do something similar to the following:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FullName", FullName));
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

When I attempt to do this in MVC6 however I run into problems with objects and methods missing. CreateIdentityAsync() and DefaultAuthenticationTypes both appear to be missing or so says visual studio and when I dig into the Identity source I can see that CreateIdentityAsync is no longer there, however I can't seem to find anything about DefaultAuthenticationTypes.

Right now at this point I think this is a nice to have, but its been driving me nuts for the past few days and would be nice to understand whats wrong or how this has changed.

Comment: `userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim("Administrator", "Allowed"));`